# How to get the login-page of openAM when the iPlanetDirectoryPro is disabled? Now is 403 forbidden page

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

openAM 13.0 tomcat8.3 apache 2.4 centos 7.2 firefox

When I ask "www.example.com:8000/demo.html", it is ok.
I get the login-page of openAM, then I input the name and password, return the page of "www.example.com:8000/demo.html".

However, I restart the openAM after I have got the page of "www.example.com:8000/demo.html", then I ask "www.example.com:8000/demo.html", return "403 forbidden". Why?

Then, I found that the iPlanetDirectoryPro in cookie is disabled. If there is a disabled iPlanetDirectoryPro in the cookie, openAM returns a "403 forbidden". But there is not a iPlanetDirectoryPro in the cookie, openAM redirect login-page of the openAm.

I hope that openAM redirect login-page when there is a disabled iPlanetDirectoryPro in the cookie. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I have changed the 403 page in Apache and set a JavaScript function to redirect to the login page of openam.

For example:

```
<script>
    var locationUrl = window.location.href;
    var redirectUrl = locationUrl.split("?")[0]; location.href="http://test.iesolutions.com.cn:8590/openamHelper/login.htm?goto="+redirectUrl;
</script>
```